# Melting pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have my pandas df like below:

```
import pandas as pd
L1 = [['ID1', 0, 'key1a', 'value1a', 'pair1a'],
      ['ID1', 2, 'key1c', 'value1c', 'pair1c'],
      ['ID1', 1, 'key1b', 'value1b', 'pair1b'],
      ['ID2', 0, 'key2a', 'value2a', 'pair2a'],
      ['ID2', 1, 'key2b', 'value2b', 'pair2b'],
      ['ID2', 2, 'key2c', 'value2c', 'pair2c']
      ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(L1,columns=['ID', 't', 'Key','Value', 'Pair'])
```

Is it possible to convert this to anything like the two option below. It looks like transpose. But, transpose is not helping.

Expected output:

```
df1=

ID1 key1a key1b key1c value1a value1b value1c  pair1a pair1b pair1c
ID2 key2a key2b key2c value2a value2b value2c  pair2a pair2b pair2c
```

**OR**

```
df1=

ID1 key1a value1a pair1a key1b value1b pair1b key1c value1c pair1c
ID2 key2a value2a pair2a key2b value2b pair2b key2c value2c pair2c
```

EDIT:
can key1a, value1a come in separate column? to process the df generated better?

Answer (score 0):

Try `agg(list)` then split list in column to multi columns

```py
cols = ['Key','Value', 'Pair']

df_ = df1.sort_values('Key').groupby('ID')[cols].agg(list)

df_ = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df_[col].values.tolist(), index=df_.index) for col in cols], axis=1, ignore_index=True).reset_index()
```

```
print(df_)

    ID      0      1      2        3        4        5       6       7       8
0  ID1  key1a  key1b  key1c  value1a  value1b  value1c  pair1a  pair1b  pair1c
1  ID2  key2a  key2b  key2c  value2a  value2b  value2c  pair2a  pair2b  pair2c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your expected in following steps:

- Sort Dataframe with respect to **Key** and `groupby()` on **ID** and get list of values for each column.
- `apply(pd.Series)` on every column using **list comprehension**
- Concatenate all dfs in that list using `pd.concat()`

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(by=['Key']).groupby(df1.ID)["Key","Value","Pair"].agg(list)
dfs = [df1[c].apply(pd.Series) for c in df1.columns]
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, ignore_index= True).reset_index()
print(df)


        ID      0      1      2        3        4        5       6       7       8
    0  ID1  key1a  key1b  key1c  value1a  value1b  value1c  pair1a  pair1b  pair1c
    1  ID2  key2a  key2b  key2c  value2a  value2b  value2c  pair2a  pair2b  pair2c
```